# How to launch Angular 2 server on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angular, npm

I am a newbie to Angular 2, and learning Angular 2 step by step follow the quickstart tutorial as [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html)

I noticed that we need to start the server when using Angular 2 as so:

```
npm start
```

I am confused about that... why do we need to start the Angular 2 server? When we use ASP.NET MVC to handle the front-end request, how can we run `npm start`?

Comment: If you use angular in your MVC application, you don't need to start the angular server. The `npm start` is only for your standalone ng2 apps

Comment: As @devqon mentioned, you don't need to start the angular server. You may find this article useful:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question, you wanted to run Angular 2 with ASP.NET MVC. I believe you do not have to run `npm start` when you using ASP.NET MVC.

There is an article to how to run Angular 2 in visual Studio. http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/.

Make sure you have install latest [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links) and follow the above link.